# System.ArgumentException:DatagridViewComboBoxCell value not valid

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, combobox

VB.net 
I have a `datagridview` set up with one column bound to another database as a `combobox`.

I had the

> System.ArgumentException:DatagridViewComboBoxCell value not valid

error constantly when I first started because there was information in the DB that was not in the `combobox`. I deleted these entries and the errored seemed to go away. As I work through my project, I still get it from time to time. In addition, the error occurs, I close the box and the DGV populates correctly and all is well.

I have a "populate" button that populates the `datagridview` and the `combobox` at the same time. I have tried delaying the `combobox` `adapterfill` statement after the datagrid `adapterfill` and it doesn't seem to have an effect.

It seems as if it only randomly occurs on the populate first click. If the first populate works, I can click again or change a filter and all is well.

One more thing. It seems to happen when there is data in the cell/row when things are populated. If I remove all data from the rows, no error. If I make some combobox selections and save, then repopulate. I can get the error.

Hope my description makes sense.

I have included the code for the populate event with the filters. Thanks.

```
Private Sub xP3PopulateBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles xP3PopulateBtn.Click

        Delay(1)
        'Active Filters
        Try
            Dim strFilterP3 As String = String.Empty
            'CheckBox Filtering code=Search for Incomplete Cells Line 2 Only 
            If xP3IncompleteCellsChkBox.Checked = True And
            xP3FirstShiftChkBox.Checked = False And
            xP3SecondShiftChkBox.Checked = False Then
                strFilterP3 = ("(DTReasonBadgeNo Is Null Or DTEventReason Is Null Or DTReasonDateTime Is Null)")
                strFilterP3 = strFilterP3 & String.Format(" And [LineID]= '3'")
                ProductionDownTimeTableBindingSource.Filter = strFilterP3
                ProductionDownTimeTableBindingSource.Sort = "ProductionUpDateTime desc"
            End If

            'CheckBox Filtering code=Search for Incomplete Cells on first and second shift only Lines 1N and 1S Only 
            If xP3IncompleteCellsChkBox.Checked = True And
            xP3FirstShiftChkBox.Checked = True And
            xP3SecondShiftChkBox.Checked = True Then
                strFilterP3 = ("(DTReasonBadgeNo Is Null Or DTEventReason Is Null Or DTReasonDateTime Is Null) And (Shift = 1 Or Shift = 2)")
                strFilterP3 = strFilterP3 & String.Format(" And [LineID]= '3'")
                ProductionDownTimeTableBindingSource.Filter = strFilterP3
                ProductionDownTimeTableBindingSource.Sort = "ProductionUpDateTime desc"
            End If

            'CheckBox Filtering code=Search for Incomplete Cells on first shift only Line 2 Only 
            If xP3IncompleteCellsChkBox.Checked = True And
       xP3FirstShiftChkBox.Checked = True And
       xP3SecondShiftChkBox.Checked = False Then
                strFilterP3 = ("(DTReasonBadgeNo Is Null Or DTEventReason Is Null Or DTReasonDateTime Is Null) and Shift = 1")
                strFilterP3 = strFilterP3 & String.Format(" and [LineID]= '3'")
                ProductionDownTimeTableBindingSource.Filter = strFilterP3
                ProductionDownTimeTableBindingSource.Sort = "ProductionUpDateTime desc"
            End If

            'CheckBox Filtering code=Search for Incomplete Cells on second shift only Line 2 Only 
            If xP3IncompleteCellsChkBox.Checked = True And
       xP3FirstShiftChkBox.Checked = False And
       xP3SecondShiftChkBox.Checked = True Then
                strFilterP3 = ("(DTReasonBadgeNo Is Null Or DTEventReason Is Null Or DTReasonDateTime Is Null) and Shift = 2")
                strFilterP3 = strFilterP3 & String.Format(" and [LineID]= '3'")
                ProductionDownTimeTableBindingSource.Filter = strFilterP3
                ProductionDownTimeTableBindingSource.Sort = "ProductionUpDateTime desc"
            End If

            'CheckBox Filtering Code=Incomplete and Complete Cells on First Shift Only Line 2 Only 
            If xP3IncompleteCellsChkBox.Checked = False And
       xP3FirstShiftChkBox.Checked = True And
       xP3SecondShiftChkBox.Checked = False Then
                strFilterP3 = "Shift = 1"
                strFilterP3 = strFilterP3 & String.Format(" and [LineID]= '3'")
                ProductionDownTimeTableBindingSource.Filter = strFilterP3
                ProductionDownTimeTableBindingSource.Sort = "ProductionUpDateTime desc"

            End If

            'CheckBox Filtering Code=Incomplete And Complete Cells on Second Shift Only Line 2 Only 
            If xP3IncompleteCellsChkBox.Checked = False And
        xP3FirstShiftChkBox.Checked = False And
        xP3SecondShiftChkBox.Checked = True Then
                strFilterP3 = "Shift = 2"
                strFilterP3 = strFilterP3 & String.Format(" and [LineID]= '3'")
                ProductionDownTimeTableBindingSource.Filter = strFilterP3
                ProductionDownTimeTableBindingSource.Sort = "ProductionUpDateTime desc"
            End If


            'CheckBox Filtering Code=S how All Line 2 Only 
            If xP3IncompleteCellsChkBox.Checked = False And
      xP3FirstShiftChkBox.Checked = False And
      xP3SecondShiftChkBox.Checked = False Then
                strFilterP3 = "1 = 1"
                strFilterP3 = strFilterP3 & String.Format(" and [LineID]= '3'")
                ProductionDownTimeTableBindingSource.Filter = strFilterP3
                ProductionDownTimeTableBindingSource.Sort = "ProductionUpDateTime desc"

            End If

            'CheckBox Filter Code Show all Data from First and Second Shift Line 2 Only  
            If xP3IncompleteCellsChkBox.Checked = False And
                xP3FirstShiftChkBox.Checked = True And
                xP3SecondShiftChkBox.Checked = True Then
                strFilterP3 = ("(Shift = 1 Or  Shift = 2)")
                strFilterP3 = strFilterP3 & String.Format(" And [LineID]= '3'")
                ProductionDownTimeTableBindingSource.Filter = strFilterP3
                ProductionDownTimeTableBindingSource.Sort = "ProductionUpDateTime desc"
            End If

            'This line of code loads data into the 'ProductionDownTimeDataSet.ProductionDownTimeTable' table.

            Me.ProductionDownTimeTableTableAdapter.Fill(Me.ProductionDownTimeDataSet1.ProductionDownTimeTable)

            'After Binding the DataSource to the ComboBox in the DatGrid, this populates the data 
            Me.DTCodeDataTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DownTimeCodesDataSet.DTCodeData)

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of arbitrarily delaying the `combobox adapterfill` statement, try filling the `ComboBox` when the `DataBindingComplete` event fires for the `DataGridView`.

Comment: Great advise! I understand now why this was occurring. I have changed the code and I haven't been able to re-create the event anymore. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @sds5150 No problem at all! I'm glad it worked out! Happy coding!